What is the difference between 遭受 and 遭到?
when I use 遭. how do I know If I have to use 受 /到？
I normally use 到, as in 遭到攻击, but I want to be sure I'm right.

What's the difference between 遭到 and 遭受?

This question is similar to: What's the difference between 遭到 and 遭受?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

"遭受" and "遭到" have similar meanings, both indicating the experience of something negative.
However, in usage, "遭受" is generally applied to a state or condition, such as in phrases like "遭受不幸" (suffer misfortune), "遭受损失" (suffer loss), or "遭受失败" (suffer defeat). On the other hand, "遭到" is typically used with actions or events, as in "遭到袭击" (come under attack), "遭到恐吓" (receive threats), or "遭到背叛" (experience betrayal).

Just to randomly pick 2 sentences:
树遭到雷击。
树遭受雷击。
北冰洋的鲸类鲸类仍然遭到猎杀。
北冰洋的鲸类鲸类仍然遭受猎杀。
The terms 遭受 and 遭到 are completely interchangeable. Personal preference will affect your choice of phrase.
